# ActiveAdmin Changing Links to Name Instead of ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

For one of my models in ActiveAdmin, it is changing the URLs to use the name instead of ID.

For example: `http://localhost:3000/admin/product/PH` instead of `http://localhost:3000/admin/product/1`

I don't understand why it's doing that since all of the other models are working correctly (using ID).

This model has no `models/product.rb` file.

```
# app/admin/product.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Product do
  permit_params :name,
    :amount,
    :description
end
```

I checked the [documentation](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters) and didn't see anything that looks like it would make this happen.

Also, all of the other SO posts I've seen related to name and URL seem to be trying to do the opposite - changing the default route to use name (instead of ID).

Comment: Could you open a rails console with ``rails c`` and paste the output of ``Product.primary_key``?

Comment: It returns `=> "id"`.

Comment: Thanks. I guess your application uses a path helper like ```admin_product_path```, but it is fed a hash, or a string as parameter instead of a plain old int. Try a recursive grep to find all occurences of ```admin_product_path``` in your app and see what parameter it is being fed. Can't think of something else.

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but I just met the same problem. 
It was due to `slug`. I just remove `slug` from my model and it worked.
Hope it could help someone.